# Finding 2 edge disjoint perfect matching in a bipartite graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, np-complete, matching-theory

Is it NP-hard to decide if an arbitrary bipartite graph has 2 edge disjoint perfect matchings? It is hard for cubic graphs, but I am not sure whether it is still hard for bipartite graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a 2-matching problem, and so is polynomial. Because the graph is bipartite, a perfect 2-matching consists in a disjoint union of even cycles, and thus can be decomposed into 2 disjoint perfect matchings.

Algorithmically, for $G = (U \cup W, E)$, this can be solved by a single maximum $st$-flow computation, where $s$ and $t$ are new vertices, with new arcs $su$ and $wt$ for all $u \in U$, $w \in W$, with capacities 2, and arcs in $E$ are oriented from $U$ to $W$ and have capacities 1.